# Using instance of class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, module, python-module

Is there a "pythonic" way to use an instance of a class for a module. For example:

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
       self.my_var = "cool value"

_instance = MyClass()

def getInstance():
    return _instance()
```

The goal is to share large lookup classes through the application instead of initializing them on every import.

Comment: "instead of initializing them on every import" - this part of your question suggests that you may have a bad mental model of how Python's import system works. Python will not redo module initialization on every import; a module is already shared between all other modules that import it.

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by "share large lookup classes through the application". Care to give an example of how you envisage this might be used?

Comment: This smells like Java to me...

Comment: What's the point of the `getInstance` function? Note, it throws an error, since you return the result of calling `_instance`, but `MyClass` objects aren't callable...

Comment: To answer all these questions I wanted to do what is in the answer below. Still not used to import in python.

Answer (score 3):

You can import anything from a module. Class instance is not an exception:

**file1.py**

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
       self.my_var = "cool value"

instance = MyClass()
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import instance
```

Answer (score 0):

If your instances are dynamically created somehow, and you **really** need to keep track of them, you can override `__new__`, like this:

```
class MyClass:
    instances = []

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        my_instance = super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        MyClass.instances.append(my_instance)
        return my_instance

a = MyClass()

print(MyClass.instances)
```

Comment: Good idea but I don't think I should mask what is really happening like this. Maybe if I was packaging this for an external project to use.